# How to display source nodes of a clicked target?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

How can I display the source nodes names of a clicked target node in a forced directed graph using D3?

The snippet below is from some [example code for directed graphs by Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). How can I go about modifying this base code so when a node is clicked on the graph, the target values of that node is displayed on the screen (in this case I would like to display the `name` attributes)?

For example the 0-th element in `"nodes"` is:

```
"nodes":[
  {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
  ...
]
```

And in `"links"` the targets are define like so:

```
"links":[
  {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},        // Napoleon
  {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},        // Mlle.Baptistine
  {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},       // Mme.Magloire
  {"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},
  {"source":4,"target":0,"value":1},        // CountessdeLo
  {"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},        // Geborand
  {"source":6,"target":0,"value":1},        // Champtercier
  {"source":7,"target":0,"value":1},        // Cravatte
  {"source":8,"target":0,"value":2},        // Count
  {"source":9,"target":0,"value":1},        // OldMan
  ...
  {"source":11,"target":0,"value":5},       // Valjean
  ...
]
```

Then clicking on the node `Myriel` would display:

> Napoleon,Mlle.Baptistine,Mme.Magloire,CountessdeLo,Geborand,Champtercier,Cravatte,Count,OldMan,Valjean

`Myriel` is located here in the graph:

[image]

Below is the JavaScript code:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
var color = d3.scale.category20();
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);
d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4062045/raw/9653f99dbf6050b0f28ceafbba659ac5e1e66fbd/miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag)
      .on("click",function(d){ 
        var targets = graph.links.filter(function(i){
          return i.target.name == d.name
        });
        tip.show( targets.map(function(i){ return i.source.name;}) );

      });
  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});
```

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
var color = d3.scale.category20();
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);
d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4062045/raw/9653f99dbf6050b0f28ceafbba659ac5e1e66fbd/miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag)
      .on("click",function(d){ 
        var targets = graph.links.filter(function(i){
          return i.target.name == d.name
        });
        tip.show( targets.map(function(i){ return i.source.name;}) );
        
      });
  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *Note:* A question like this was posted by a user, in which I thought an answer would be valuable to the site. Although the user deleted their question before I was able to post my solution. Hence I re-created the question with additional information so I could share my answer. Other answers are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a click event on each node, then inside we can get all the `targets` by filtering the `graph.links` array such that we only have the elements who's `target.name` is the same as the clicked nodes name `d.name`. Once we have that you can use `.map()` to return the array with `.source.name` to give the `name` of those items inside `targets`:

```
  .on("click",function(d) { 
    var targets = graph.links.filter(function(i){
      return i.target.name==d.name;
    });
    tip.show( targets.map(function(i){ return i.source.name; }) );
  });
```

```js
var tip = d3.tip().attr('class', 'd3-tip').html(function(d) { return d; });

var width = 960,
    height = 500;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.call(tip);

var color = d3.scale.category20();
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);
d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4062045/raw/9653f99dbf6050b0f28ceafbba659ac5e1e66fbd/miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag)
      .on("click",function(d){ 
        var targets = graph.links.filter(function(i){
          return i.target.name == d.name
        });
        tip.show( targets.map(function(i){ return i.source.name;}) );
        
      });
  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.6.7/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
```

Now for easy display of those values the [**d3-tip**](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip) library can be used. This would be initialized for the graph like so:

```
var tip = d3.tip().attr('class', 'd3-tip').html(function(d) { return d; });
...
var svg = ..
svg.call(tip);
```

And finally the `tip.show(...)` function in the first code snippet will display those items on the graph.